# Better way to replace my function?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I have attached a json data link for download-

[json data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YWx9YF-Ai8S11Dwy9jTU0_REmwPmoakD/view?usp=sharing)

Currently I have written following function for getting each level of children data into a combined dataframe-

```
def get_children(catMapping):
    level4 = json_normalize(catMapping['SuccessResponse']['Body'],
                                        ['children', 'children', 'children', 'children', ['children']])
    level3 = json_normalize(catMapping['SuccessResponse']['Body'],
                                        ['children', 'children', 'children', ['children']])
                        ['children', 'children', ['children']])
    level1 = json_normalize(catMapping['SuccessResponse']['Body'],
                                        ['children', ['children']])
    level0 = json_normalize(catMapping['SuccessResponse']['Body'],
                                        ['children'])

    combined = pd.concat([level0, level1, level2, level3,level4])
    combined = combined.reset_index(drop=True)

    return combined
```

And it looks like this is not the recommended way but I am unable to write a function which can traverse each level.

Can you please help me with any better function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that recursively iterate all items:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

with open(r"data.json", "r") as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())

def nest_iter(items):
    for item in items:
        children_ids = [o["categoryId"] for o in item["children"]]
        ret_item = item.copy()
        ret_item["children"] = children_ids
        yield ret_item
        yield from nest_iter(item["children"])

df = pd.DataFrame(nest_iter(data['SuccessResponse']['Body']))
```

the result:

```
      categoryId                        children   leaf         name    var
....
4970    10001244                              []   True     Business  False
4971    10001245                              []   True       Casual  False
4972    10001246                              []   True      Fashion  False
4973    10001247                              []   True       Sports  False
4974        7756  [7761, 7758, 7757, 7759, 7760]  False        Women  False
4975        7761                              []   True  Accessories  False
4976        7758                              []   True     Business  False
4977        7757                              []   True       Casual  False
4978        7759                              []   True      Fashion  False
4979        7760                              []   True       Sports  False
```

Comment: Hm, why would you use `literal_eval` instead of the `json` package?

Comment: Oh, I get it, the data is not really JSON. Single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Thanks @HYRY..it's helpful. I will test this and share the outcome soon.